Issues with legs vibrating and contact flickering in gazebo ros noeitc
I am having issues with simulating my custom robot. The video can be seen here video.
I have no clue why the legs are shaking. Here is the limit of revolute joints.
  <limit
      lower="-3.14159"
      upper="3.14159"
      effort="30"
      velocity="10" />

and here is the kp and kd
  <gazebo reference="TL4">
    <kp>1000000</kp>
    <kd>10000</kd>
  </gazebo>


Maybe u wanna try to reduce that Kp and Kd, seems excessively high to me. Try from Kp = 1 and Kd = 0.
